# Travelling Salesman with Momentum?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman

I have a task that is very similar to travelling salesman problem (TSP), but I'm not sure if it's easily mappable to TSP.  I'm wondering if this variant has a name and known solvers already, or can be just reduced to TSP somehow.

I have a graph where nodes are (x, y) locations, and edges are smooth, continuous paths connecting those locations.  As in normal TSP, the task is to visit every node while covering as little distance as possible.

The difference is that nodes have a particular orientation - and the paths linking them are constrained to pass through the node at this same orientation.  You cannot just do a sudden U-turn at a node - you have to keep going the same direction as when you entered - so there is this additional bit of "state" or "momentum" associated with your direction of travel.  See below picture for a visualization.

Is this mappable to generic TSP in some simple way that I'm not thinking of right now?  Or if not, does this variant have a name of its own?

**Edit**: It helps to think of the problem as trying to route a train that can never stop through all the cities as efficiently as possible.  If this problem has no name, it could be called [Travelling Post Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_Post_Office).

[image]

In the above, a solution (possibly not the best) starting/ending at node 0 is `0->1->2->3->0->1->7->6->5->0->1->2->4->6->7->1->0`.

**Edit** - Actually, the above solution does not work if we require that the end orientation matches the start orientation.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the restriction just that you can't use the same edge twice in a row (e.g. go from node A to B, and then immediately back to A), or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I don't think this is a graph, since it contains information about the "edge orientation".   There *may* be some specialization of TSP to planar graphs.

Comment: user3386109 - slightly more than that - you cannot leave a node from any edge that leaves the node in the same direction you entered from (ie no U-turns).   You must exit the node in the opposite direction from which you entered (due to smoothness constraint - there are only 2 directions from which you can enter/exit node, 180deg apart)

Comment: Seems like you can model this as a directed graph where a node with `n` edges is split into `n*2` nodes. In your example `n` is always 3, so each node becomes 6 nodes, 3 of which have incoming connections from other groups, and 3 which have outgoing connections to other groups. Then you need a TSP solver that works with directed graphs (pretty sure those exist). The downside, of course, is that you're starting with a much bigger graph.

Comment: @user3386109 But you do not need to visit all edges, you only need to visit all nodes.  So it is a little different.

Comment: Yes exactly - the solver would have to know that it only needs to visit 1 of the `2n` nodes associated with one "original" node - so it seems like this mapping wouldn't work.

Comment: @btilly and @ Peter: Ah yes, that does takes it out of the realm of ready-made solvers. The solver would need to be tweaked so that a visit to any of the `n` incoming nodes marks all `n` incoming nodes as visited, and the subsequent unavoidable visit to an outgoing node marks all `n` outgoing nodes as visited.

Comment: I wonder if the `python` tag is in order here, since momentum seems to be some python library or something.

Comment: "momentum" here refers to the fact that no U-turns are allowed in the graph traversal

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Here's [a link to the code](https://github.com/ghostFaceKillah/tsp-momentum/) that solves it (or at least the example posted above).

Explaination:

Let's take funky-graph `G` with `n` nodes and tri-edges `(i, j ,k)`.

We will represent a set of edges as a set of integers `e_{ijk}` which  denote how many times tri-edge `(i, j, k)` has been traversed. For example simple traversal of 3-graph is `(0, 1, 2)`, `(1, 2, 0)`, `(2, 0, 1)`. Here `e_{012} = e_{120} = e_{201} = 1` and `e_{ijk} = 0` for all other `i, j, k` triplets.

Now we will cast the problem of finding a traversal of a funky graph  as a mixed linear programming problem.

Let's consider edge `(i, j, k)`. We define transition matrix `T_{ijk}`
associated with this edge. It will be `n x n` matrix that is all
zeros, apart from 2 places. `T_{ijk}[i, j] = -1`  and `T_{ijk}[j, k] = -1`.

So for example

```
           [0 0 0]
T_{120} =  [0 0 -1]
           [1 0 0]
```

(Note that we count numbers from 0, like computer scientists).

Now if for a set of edges we have

```
    \sum_{ijk} e_{ijk} T_{ijk} = 0
```

it means that this set of edges represents a cycle.

We can now flatten / reshape these matrices $T_{ijk}$ into vectors.
For example $T_{120}$ becomes

```
t_{120} = [0 0 0 0 0 -1 1 0 0]
```

And in this way our constraint from above becomes a matrix constraint

```
Te = 0
```

where `T` is a matrix with `n^2` rows and `n^3` columns.
Each column has either exactly one `1` at `jn + j`th place and exactly one `-1` at `in + k`th place if `ijk` is smooth or is all zeros if tri-edge `ijk` is not smooth and therefore not traversable.

The second constraint that we want is that visited at least once.
(TODO for tomorrow me to fill in details here).

And that's it! We just plug it into MIP (Mixed Integer Program) solver. Like this one https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip